# Consuming JSON with encoded url

Tags: json

I am trying to get response from Java system which will send response in the JSON data format.

For request , the HTTP Method is POST , 
Content Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and

Input params is

credentials=user10,TCS&password=TCS&action=getUserItem
s&domainName=user10&departmentId=

The url to connect the system is http://www.trex:5500/TCS/IntServelt

To connect the JAVA Restful services , below are my queries:

1. Should I form the url as

http://www.trex:5500/TCS/IntServelt&credentials=user10,TCS&password=TCS&action=getUserItems&domainName=user10&departmentId=

I have just copy pasted the Input parameter in the provided url ?

1. Does the sequence of the parameter matters? Is there any format for that?

Please share inputs.

Regards

Comment: Typically the format is something like <base URL>?key=val&key2=val but in your example you have an ampersand after the base URL and there's no value associated with departmentId. Just a couple of quick observations.

Comment: Dear Mike, Yes I missed the ? after the base url. My next query would be whether the sequence of the key matters? Is this going to create any runtime error. Client has provided me these input parameters to access the services. Do all the provided input parameters are mandatory to access the services.

Comment: &name=value pairs don't matter for order, unless you care about SEO/keeping urls consistant through a mod_re-writer, etc